# Is there any way to simplify the Javascript part on this Dropdown list example?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to simplify and make the JavaScript part of this code less complicated?
I have a `div` acting as a dropdown list.
Once the list item is selected, it updates the input text field with the selection, and the dropdown button as well.

```
$("#dropdown-list-item1").click(function() {
          $("#dropdown-value").val("Item1");
          $("#dropdown-button-label").text("Item1");
          $("#dropdown-list").hide();
          $("#dropdown-list-item1").addClass("active");
          $("#dropdown-list-item2").removeClass("active");
          $("#dropdown-list-item3").removeClass("active");
          $("#dropdown-list-item4").removeClass("active");
          $("#dropdown-list-item5").removeClass("active");
          $("#dropdown-list-item6").removeClass("active");
          $("#dropdown-list-item7").removeClass("active");
          $("#dropdown-list-item8").removeClass("active");
     });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2reza3L6/2/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the selector `[id^="dropdown-list-item"]` to select all elements which have an ID which starts with `dropdown-list-item`:

```
$("#dropdown-list-item1").click(function() {
  $("#dropdown-value").val("Item1");
  $("#dropdown-button-label").text("Item1");
  $("#dropdown-list").hide();
  $("[id^='dropdown-list-item']").removeClass("active");
  $("#dropdown-list-item1").addClass("active");
});
```

But it would be better to use classes instead - numeric indexed IDs are quite a code smell.

Or, you could use `#dropdown-list > div` to select all the children:

```
<div class="active">
  Item1
</div>
<div>
  Item2
</div>
<div>
  Item3
</div>
```

and

```
const items = $("#dropdown-list > div");
items.click(function() {
  const index = items.index(this) + 1;
  $("#dropdown-value").val("Item" + index);
  $("#dropdown-button-label").text("Item" + index);
  $("#dropdown-list").hide();

  items.removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```js
$("#dropdown-list").hide();

$("#dropdown-button").click(function() {
  $("#dropdown-list").toggle();
});

const items = $("#dropdown-list > div");
items.click(function() {
  const index = items.index(this) + 1;
  $("#dropdown-value").val("Item" + index);
  $("#dropdown-button-label").text("Item" + index);
  $("#dropdown-list").hide();

  items.removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
#dropdown {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 21px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 100px);
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#dropdown-button {
  border: 1px solid #0168FA;
  background-color: #0168FA;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

#dropdown-list {
  margin-top: 25px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #8392A545;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#dropdown-list-item1,
#dropdown-list-item2,
#dropdown-list-item3,
#dropdown-list-item4,
#dropdown-list-item5,
#dropdown-list-item6,
#dropdown-list-item7,
#dropdown-list-item8 {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
}

#dropdown-list-item1:hover,
#dropdown-list-item2:hover,
#dropdown-list-item3:hover,
#dropdown-list-item4:hover,
#dropdown-list-item5:hover,
#dropdown-list-item6:hover,
#dropdown-list-item7:hover,
#dropdown-list-item8:hover,
.active {
  border: 1px solid #0168FA !important;
  background-color: #0168FA;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="dropdown-value" value="Item1">

<div id="dropdown">
  <div id="dropdown-button">
    <div id="dropdown-button-label">
      Item1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="dropdown-list">
    <div class="active">
      Item1
    </div>
    <div>
      Item2
    </div>
    <div>
      Item3
    </div>
    <div>
      Item4
    </div>
    <div>
      Item5
    </div>
    <div>
      Item6
    </div>
    <div>
      Item7
    </div>
    <div>
      Item8
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course.

```
$("#dropdown-list-item1").click(function() {
    $("#dropdown-value").val("Item1");
    $("#dropdown-button-label").text("Item1");
    $("#dropdown-list").hide();
    $("#dropdown-list-item1").addClass("active");
    for(var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) 
        $("#dropdown-list-item"+i).removeClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't the removeClass be first and then addClass at the end? This way the added class will be removed as well?

Comment: @Tibby No. This is your exact code just with a loop instead of the 8 `dropdown-list-item` statements.

Comment: I See that, but the addClass is before the removeClass loop. So whatever you add on before the loop, it will remove. I think the removeClass loop should be first and then the addClass for each dropdown-list-item.